# Setting event handlers on react hooks (useEffect)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

This component always alerts 0 when you press a key: ([run it online](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GH9E8D7X5UKZ))

```
const Hello = () => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = React.useState(0)
  let canvas = React.useRef()
  let add = () => {
    setCounter(counter + 3)
    alert(counter)
  }
  React.useEffect(() => {
    window.onkeydown = add
  }, [])
  return <div><h1>{counter}</h1></div>
}
```

But my desire output is alerting current state, not initial state.

If i change it to :

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    window.onkeydown = add
  })
```

It works fine (binding `add` event handler to `onkeydown` on every render.).

But why it behaves likes this? (i don't want to bind an event handler on every render cause it seems to have performance issues)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issue

You are enclosing the initial state in the attached callback by only setting the callback when the component mounts using an empty dependency array. A functional state update won't have this issue as it uses a callback function to compute and return a new state value from the previous state value.

## Solution

- The effect needs to add an event listener correctly. (*and return a cleanup function!!*)
- State update should be a functional update since it *depends* on previous state.
- State updates are asynchronous in nature, so alerting or logging it right after it is enqueued will only log the *current* state value from the *current* render cycle. Use an effect to do anything with the updated state.

Updated code

```
const Hello = () => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = React.useState(0);
  let canvas = React.useRef();

  const add = () => {
    setCounter(counter => counter + 3);
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log(counter); // or alert, if you really want to
  }, [counter]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("keydown", add);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("keydown", add);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{counter}</h1>
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit Add window event listener]

Comment: thanks. but it will re attach event handler on every update of counter, right? can't we prevent it?

Comment: @yaya Yes, seems that is the case and can work, with a caveat though. I've updated answer.

Comment: @yaya Is it *actually* an issue to use the first implementation? How often is a key down event firing? Are you sure it's the react code that's slow, or is it the side-effect of console logging or alerting that is slowing the UI down?

Comment: i didn't have any specific performance issue, i just wanted to do it in the right way. your suggested way worked fine. thanks.

Comment: may i ask which pattern is better practice and more common? 1. adding event listener on start, and using `functional updates to update state` (your first answer), or adding event listener on update, and not using `functional updates to update state` ? (your edited answer)

Comment: @yaya The common pattern is the first answer, to add event listeners when the component mounts, and remove the listener when the component unmounts. What complicates it a bit is when the event callback *also* references state in functional components. The state value from the render cycle the listeners are added is enclosed in the callback, so this is why it needs to be added to the effect's dependency array, to re-enclose the next current state value. Functional state updates solve a different, separate problem.

Comment: can you take a look at this: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GH9HX5EEL5FM ? this solves this problem with `Functional state update`, doesn't it? the benefit is that it only add listener on mount, unlike your first answer. (since you added counter as dependency, it will reattach handler on every update.)

Comment: i think you can remove the edit part since as you said using `window.onkeydown` is a bad practice and your updated code is just fine, and it makes the answer so long. (it's just a suggestion). thanks again for answer.

Answer (score 0):

Passing an empty array will trigger the `useEffect` only at the mounting of the component, just add the counter in the array in order for it to be triggered every time the state is updated.

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    window.onkeydown = add
  }, [counter])
```

Comment: passing empty array will call the callback only once at the initial mounting of the component

Comment: as @gagangaur said, an empty array results the callback at the mounting of the of the component just like `ComponentDidMount()` in older React and not each the component is updated, you have to 'hook' the effect to some state, and the effect then gets called when the state is updated.

Comment: @alikondie really sorry for wrong statement i said. you're right. i was passing an empty array, but it was by intend. i'm trying to prevent reattaching an event handler on every update of counter, just like the other answer. do you think it's a better practice to do it this way?

Comment: If you don't intend to execute the event on every update, I suggest you add another state as a trigger and update it whenever you want to execute the event, otherwise, I don't see another better solution.